# Is the Intel HD 4000 GPU good enough for everyday use?

Tags: macbook-pro, macbook-air, macbook-pro-retina

I am about to get a Mac, and right now I'm weighing two options that I can get.

I can get a new MacBook Air 2015 at the lowest specs:

- 4 GB RAM
- 2 core 1.6 GHz (turbo to 2.7) i5 CPU
- 128 GB PCI-e SSD
- 1366x768 screen
- HD 6000 graphics (800ish GFLOPS)

Or, I can get a used (but in very good condition) 13 inch retina early 2013 MacBook pro with mid-tier configuration. Specs:

- 8 GB RAM
- 2 core 2.5 GHz(turbo to 3.1) i5 CPU
- 256 GB PCI-e SSD
- 2560x1600 screen
- HD 4000 GPU (330ish GFLOPS)

I don't care about compactness or battery life, they aren't different enough between the two machines to affect my decision. The Pro has really good specs except for the GPU, but I plan to use the laptop more for development, schoolwork, and casual but not intensive gaming. After all, it is a Mac, not intended to be a gaming PC. For development (that may end up partially being gamedev) and schoolwork (google drive use), do you see any major reason the HD 4000 might cause problems?

Comment: Some game development ay? One notable "positive" about going with the HD 4000 is that you'll find yourself coding for (more or less) a lowest-common-denominator graphics platform. That may well be a good thing, especially if you want to maximize your potential market.

Comment: @misha256 that's a great point, since I'm definitely not planning on doing anything super advanced and graphically intensive, I'll have a good benchmark.

Comment: I use the HD4000 in my Dell Laptop from 2013 and I have no issues so far under Windows 8 using dev tools (Visual Studio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HD 4000 will perform well for the tasks you're looking to do. As **misha256** commented, you'll be developing for the lowest graphics capabilities which expands your userbase (providing you're doing that kind of development).

Tom's Hardware and Anandtech did a review of the HD4000 and you can view their comprehensive notes on the links (and surrounding pages on those links) below:

Tom's: [Link](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/ivy-bridge-benchmark-core-i7-3770k,3181-4.html)

Anandtech: [Link](http://www.anandtech.com/show/5771/the-intel-ivy-bridge-core-i7-3770k-review/8)